# How can I generate multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: numpy, statistics, gaussian

I am trying to generate the 1000 samples from a gaussian distribution with the following code

```
mean = [2.2, 0]
cov = [[1, 1.5], [1.5, 1]]
x = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,1000)
```

But above code is giving me the runtime error of `RuntimeWarning: covariance is not positive-semidefinite.`

how can I fix this?

Comment: simply put, for the case 2x2, `cov` matrix needs to have positive determinant.

Comment: Yeah, Just noticed it now. The resultant of `cov` was negative hence it was giving the error. Thanks for the quick reply